# CCRC ClearCase Remote Client - Examining view configuration details

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

I'm using only CCRC  - I don't have ClearCase locally installed.
I use CCRC Version: 7.1.1   Build id: 7.1.1.03.00_2010C.D100803

I'm working  with a mature user of ClearCase - they have hundreds of work streams in a complex child parent relationship tree.  When I create a view or stream CCRC offers me a picture of this complex tree and the location of my view (or stream if I'm creating a stream).

However, once my local view is set up there appears to be no mechanism for checking the location of any views.  CCRC menus which 'show ClearCase view configuration' only show the load rules (i.e. which VOB's I'm currently selecting).

Another [post to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318279/delete-clearcase-views-script/4319090#4319090) tells me that '`.ccase_wvreg`' lists the local file paths where local copies of the files are stored. But '.ccase_wvreg' doesn't show the logical name of the views.

**So how does CCRC find a map the logical view names and their configuration?**
Is there another file I can examine (or other work around?) which would show  me the complete  view configuration.
The only workaround I have today (other than being incredibly careful and keeping png images of the stream as I set it up) is to commence the process of creating a new view or stream and retrace my steps.

Its surprising that being able to confirm the location of a view is so difficult - given what happens if one mistakenly checks in or deliver to the wrong stream!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [CLI (Command Line Interface) for CCRC](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24021929) might be able to provide more information, espcially regarding the config spec of your view, in which there should be mentioned the name of the associated Stream.

```
catcs [-username user-name][-ser/ver server-url][-pas/sword user-password]\
      [-tag view-tag]
```

But check first in the properties of the view. It can also include that information.

Comment: Actually the answer was staring me in the face.  CCRC, just like subversion and CVS, clutters up the checkout with lots of little control files - in the case of CCRC they are called '.copyarea.dat'.   With a little care and common sense one can use notepad++ to read them (taking great care not to modify them) - they contain all I need to know. 

As with subversion and cvs,  I'd suspect that inappropriate copying of .copyarea.dat files will cause catastrophic and confusing failures – it certainly does in CVS, it's not something I'd want to try!

Comment: Sorry - ignore previous comment -  '.copyarea.dat' only contains the VOB list (VOBs and streams have very similar names on the system I'm using.)

Comment: @Tony: I checked: selecting the properties of your view ("Show Properties" will display the name of the Stream associated with your view.