# How to delete Clear-Case view from local disk

Tags: clearcase

I created a Snapshot Clear-Case view (Say `View_1`) in my local drive.
After a long time it got finished up with some errors w.r.t. some files.

I created another view (Say `View_2`) at some other folder structure on ma local drive, which got created successfully without any error.
Now due to HDD space constrained, I wanted to delete `View_1`.

Is this is OK to delete a corrupted view from my local machine?

If not, then why?

Answer (score 1):

You can delete it directly, but it would still exist for ClearCase (still `[being registered][1]`).

Better would be to do:

```
cd c:\parent\dir_of_View_1
cleartool rmview View_1
```

If you have already deleted (not through cleartool, but with a simple Windows delete) the `View_1` directory, you still can unregister that view, through [script like `nuke_view.pl`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4319090/6309): [`rmtag` + `unregister` view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9782443/6309).

Note: this answer assumes that `View_1` and `View_2` are two different ClearCase views, not two different root directory of the same ClearCase view (loaded twice).