# How to Move Clear Case View from one machine to another machine.

Tags: clearcase

i tried all answer posted here but its not works for me. also refer this link but some error.

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/t_viewadm_mv_1arch.htm
i have some views in my old machine and i want to move those views to my new machine completely.

some change set is associated with those views.
Please give step  by step solution, i am new with clear case.

Answer (score 0):

If moving the view doesn't work properly, I would recommend simply to:

- get the old view config spec (`cleartool catcs <view_tag>`)
- make sure there is not checked out files
- [nuke the view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4319090/6309) (meaning unregister it completely)
- recreate it on the new machine, and set the same config spec.

The "change sets" (UCM activities) will there in the new view.